# What version of Operator Lifecycle Manager (OLM) am I running in my cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, operator-lifecycle-manager

I'm running an OpenShift cluster and am trying to figure out what version of OLM in installed in it. I'm considering an upgrade, but would like more details.

How can I find the version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**From the CLI:**

You can change kubectl for oc since you are using OpenShift.

First find the name of an olm-operator pod. I'm assuming Operator Lifecycle Manager is installed in the olm namespace, but it might be "operator-lifecycle-manager".

```
kubectl get pods -n olm |grep olm-operator
```

Then run a command on that pod like this:

```
kubectl exec -n olm <POD_NAME> -- olm --version
```

**From the Console:**

Navigate to the namespace and find an olm-operator pod. Open the "Terminal" tap and run `olm --version`.

In either case, the output should be something like this:

```
OLM version: 0.12.0
git commit: a611449366805935939777d0182a86ba43b26cbd
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be determined from the version of the `packageserver` CSV (ClusterServiceVersion) object.

```
$oc get csv packageserver -n openshift-operator-lifecycle-manager
NAME            DISPLAY          VERSION   REPLACES   PHASE
packageserver   Package Server   0.19.0               Succeeded
```

If on plain Kubernetes then query the same from the `olm` namespace:

```
$kubectl get csv packageserver -n olm
```